# how to get phoenix-4.7.0-HBase-1.1-client-spark.jar package

Tags: apache-spark, apache-phoenix

I don't known where i can get the phoenix--client-spark.jar.

I have find it from *phoenix-4.7.0-HBase-1.0-bin.tar.gz* , but i can't find it.

Comment: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/phoenix/phoenix-spark/4.7.0-HBase-1.1/

Comment: thanks Paul Bastide, I can't find `phoenix-4.7.0-HBase-1.1-client-spark.jar` ,just find `phoenix-spark-4.7.0-HBase-1.1.jar `

Comment: I think around 4.7/4.8 they split them out.  It may only be in 4.8.  not entirely certain

Comment: thanks, i will be retry to find it by other way.

Answer (score 0):

add both

> phoenix-4.8.1-HBase-1.2-client.jar
>
> phoenix-spark-4.8.1-HBase-1.2.jar

the JDBC class comes with phoenix-4.8.1-HBase-1.2-client.jar